# run .jar with arguments from a java program and get the output

Tags: java, jar

Right now I'm working doing some test automation for certain devices, the thing is, i have a .jar file that executes all the test from cmd.exe and i want to automate this with a java script, so I can run it and read the output. My .jar file uses a few arguments to execute, like this:

> -java jar MyFile.jar arg1 arg2

I'm really lost so i would really appreciate your help with this. I've tried so far a lot of codes I´ve found on the web and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Java Script is not Java](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Javascript_is_not_Java) ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no problem executing the main class (entry point) in your jar.file , command line parameters are passed to a String array of the static main method in your class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length>0){
        System.out.println(args[0]); // arg1 parameter given in command line
        System.out.println(args[1]); // arg2 parameter given in command line
    }
}
```